# Pandas: df.refill, adding two columns of different shape

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with these entries

```
Timestamp       Spread
34200.405839234 0.18
34201.908794218 0.17
...
```

CSV File available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qfoa3t924ttpa5x/stockA.csv)

I imported the csv file as follow:

```
df = pd.read_csv(stock1.csv,index_col=None,usecols=['Timestamp','Spread'], header=0, dtype=np.float)   

df=DataFrame(df)
```

I then reformat the column of Timestamp as follow:

```
df['Time'] = (df.Timestamp * 1e9).astype('timedelta64[ns]')+ pd.to_datetime(date)
```

Therefore, my first column `Time` in my dataframe `df` looks like:

```
815816   2011-01-10 15:59:59.970055123
815815   2011-01-10 15:59:59.945755073
815814   2011-01-10 15:59:59.914206190
815813   2011-01-10 15:59:59.913996055
815812   2011-01-10 15:59:59.889747847
815811   2011-01-10 15:59:59.883946409
815810   2011-01-10 15:59:59.881460044
Name: Time, Length: 110, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I also have another column in another dataframe constructed as follow:

```
start = pd.Timestamp(date+'T09:30:00')
end = pd.Timestamp(date+'T16:00:00')
x=pd.date_range(start,end,freq='S')
x=pd.DataFrame(x)

print x

4993 2011-01-10 10:53:13
4994 2011-01-10 10:53:14
4995 2011-01-10 10:53:15
4996 2011-01-10 10:53:16
4997 2011-01-10 10:53:17
4998 2011-01-10 10:53:18
4999 2011-01-10 10:53:19
[23401 rows x 1 columns]
```

I wish to do the following:

```
data = df.reindex(df.Time + x)
data = data.ffill()
```

I get

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2574110) (110)
```

which of course as to do with the length of `x`. How can I "reshape" x to merge both? I looked online on how to modify the length but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the index first, otherwise what you were doing was correct. You can't directly add a Series of datetimes (e.g the `df.Time`) and and index range. You want a union (so you can be explicity and use `.union` or convert to an index, which '+' does by default between 2 indexes).

```
In [35]: intervals = np.random.randint(0,1000,size=100).cumsum()

In [36]: df = DataFrame({'time' : [ Timestamp('20140101')+pd.offsets.Milli(i) for i in intervals ],
                         'value' : np.random.randn(len(intervals))})

In [37]: df.head()
Out[37]: 
                        time     value
0 2014-01-01 00:00:00.946000 -0.322091
1 2014-01-01 00:00:01.127000  0.887412
2 2014-01-01 00:00:01.690000  0.537789
3 2014-01-01 00:00:02.332000  0.311556
4 2014-01-01 00:00:02.335000  0.273509

[5 rows x 2 columns]

In [40]: date_range('20140101 00:00:00','20140101 01:00:00',freq='s')
Out[40]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2014-01-01 01:00:00]
Length: 3601, Freq: S, Timezone: None

 In [38]: new_range = date_range('20140101 00:00:00','20140101 01:00:00',freq='s') + Index(df.time)

In [39]: new_range
Out[39]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2014-01-01 01:00:00]
Length: 3701, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [42]: df.set_index('time').reindex(new_range).head()
Out[42]: 
                               value
2014-01-01 00:00:00              NaN
2014-01-01 00:00:00.946000 -0.322091
2014-01-01 00:00:01              NaN
2014-01-01 00:00:01.127000  0.887412
2014-01-01 00:00:01.690000  0.537789

[5 rows x 1 columns]

In [44]: df.set_index('time').reindex(new_range).ffill().head(10)
Out[44]: 
                               value
2014-01-01 00:00:00              NaN
2014-01-01 00:00:00.946000 -0.322091
2014-01-01 00:00:01        -0.322091
2014-01-01 00:00:01.127000  0.887412
2014-01-01 00:00:01.690000  0.537789
2014-01-01 00:00:02         0.537789
2014-01-01 00:00:02.332000  0.311556
2014-01-01 00:00:02.335000  0.273509
2014-01-01 00:00:03         0.273509
2014-01-01 00:00:03.245000 -1.034595

[10 rows x 1 columns]
```

From the provided csv file (which FYI is named 'stocksA.csv') (and you don't need to 
do `df=DataFrame(df)` as its already a frame (nor do you need to specify the dtype)

You have duplicates on the Time column

```
In [34]: df.drop_duplicates(['Time']).set_index('Time').reindex(new_range).info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 49354 entries, 2011-01-10 09:29:59.999400 to 2011-01-10 16:00:00
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Timestamp    25954 non-null float64
Spread       25954 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)

In [35]: df.drop_duplicates(['Time']).set_index('Time').reindex(new_range).ffill().info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 49354 entries, 2011-01-10 09:29:59.999400 to 2011-01-10 16:00:00
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Timestamp    49354 non-null float64
Spread       49354 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)

In [36]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 45782 entries, 0 to 45781
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Timestamp    45782 non-null float64
Spread       45782 non-null int64
Time         45782 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1)

In [37]: df.drop_duplicates(['Time','Spread']).info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 26171 entries, 0 to 45780
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Timestamp    26171 non-null float64
Spread       26171 non-null int64
Time         26171 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1)
```

So prob easiest to simply drop them and reindex to the new times you want. If you WANT to preserver Time/spread duplicates then this becomes a much more complicated problem. You will have to either use a multi-index and loop on the duplicates or better yet just resample the data down (e.g. say mean or something).

Here is how to deal with your duplicate data; groupby it by the duplicated column and perform an operation (here `mean`). You should do this before the reindexing step.

```
In [13]: df.groupby('Time')['Spread'].mean()
Out[13]: 
Time
2011-01-10 09:29:59.999400       2800
2011-01-10 09:30:00.000940       3800
2011-01-10 09:30:00.010130       1100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.018500       1100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.020060       1100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.020980       1100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.024570        100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.024769999     100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.028210       1100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.037950       1100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.038880       1100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.039140       1100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.040410       1100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.041510        100
2011-01-10 09:30:00.042530        100
...
2011-01-10 09:40:32.850540       300
2011-01-10 09:40:32.862300       300
2011-01-10 09:40:32.937410       300
2011-01-10 09:40:33.001750       300
2011-01-10 09:40:33.129500       300
2011-01-10 09:40:33.129650       300
2011-01-10 09:40:33.131560       300
2011-01-10 09:40:33.136100       200
2011-01-10 09:40:33.136310       200
2011-01-10 09:40:33.136560       200
2011-01-10 09:40:33.137590       200
2011-01-10 09:40:33.137640       200
2011-01-10 09:40:33.137850       200
2011-01-10 09:40:33.138840       200
2011-01-10 09:40:33.154219999    200
Name: Spread, Length: 25954
```

Comment: thanks but for `df.set_index('time').reindex(new_range)` I get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` and that's maybe due to the fact that `df.Time` is in `dtype: datetime64[ns]` since I have nanoseconds

Comment: try: ``(Index(df.Time) + date_range(.....)).unique()``; the goal is to create a combined (unique) index that you to reindex to; nanosecons work fine (just simpler for the example above)

Comment: If I do `new_range = (pd.date_range('20110110 09:30:00','20110110 16:00:00',freq='s') + pd.Index(df.Time)).unique
df.set_index('Time').reindex(new_range)` I get `TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable`. Thanks for the help

Comment: sorry I forgot the `()` but I still get an error: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: its: `new_range = (pd.date_range('20110110 09:30:00','20110110 16:00:00',freq='s')+pd.Index(df.Time)).unique()` 
`df.set_index('Time').reindex(new_range)`

Comment: no, what I mean is the code to create ``df.Time`` (or post somewhere)

Comment: sorry! I updated my code above on how I generated `df.['Time']`. It is basically `df['Time'] = (df.Timestamp * 1e9).astype('timedelta64[ns]')+ pd.to_datetime(date)`

Comment: can you post that csv (and should exactly what code you are using to read in)? or at least that column. Its' impossible to figure out what you are doing otherwise.

Comment: I updated my question above with what is in the csv and the code that I use to read the csv

Comment: I need the actual csv. pretend I need to see your data EXACTLY.

Comment: there is a link to my CSV file in my question

Comment: I updated; you have duplicates on the Time column. See my comments.

Comment: thank you for the help... I never thought the duplicates could have been an issue. Now what I have to do is to make sure all the `time` observations are unique and if not, I will take the mean of the spread for the duplicated time. Not too sure how to do this in Pandas but I will figure it out.

Comment: ``resample(..)`` is your friend

Comment: what is the `rule` input I should use in `reshape` to handle nanoseconds? Will it just remove the duplicates by taking the mean of `Spread`?

Comment: You can't actually resample this at the nanosecond level it will blow up your memory, but see above for an easy way.